# How to make Chrome "Find on page" find dynamically loaded text (loaded after page, like AJAX)?

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome (49.0.2623.87) on OS X 10.10.5, when I use the "Find" feature to search for text on the current page it does not consider any text which has been loaded dynamically after the page finished loading. This problem has a workaround which is to delete a character from the end of the search text and re-enter it, which seems to reset something and makes Chrome re-scan the page and find the text correctly.

How can I make Chrome find the text without having to reset the search, i.e. by just hitting the "Find Next" shortcut?

Comment: Seems like there's no real solution to this problem at the moment. If you were using Windows, I'd recommend using AutoIT or AutoHotkey to set up a keyboard macro that presses `Ctrl`+`F`, `End` and types a character and deletes it when you press an associated hotkey. I guess you could use [Keyboard Maestro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153930/autohotkey-equivalent-for-os-x) on a Mac for the same thing, but I wouldn't know for sure as I haven't used it.

Answer (score 2):

Constantly scanning the same page again and again for a phrase can be a drain on computer resources which is probably why this feature isn't implemented in web browsers *(or maybe the developers just never thought of it*).

As far as I know, this feature doesn't exist in any popular browser.

The only current work around for chrome is:

Press Ctrl+F

After the text has been dynamically changed, Press 'Esc' and then press 'Ctrl+F' again

Press 'Enter'.

Comment: The browser knows when it loads dynamic content thanks to events so there is no need to "constantly" scan anything, just after events that change text in the DOM.

Comment: @tubes Point taken... Like I said, this probably didn't occur to the developers

Comment: I'm 100% certain this won't work for reddit's "my comments" page or on the Stack Overflow Dev Survey, because I tried this on both of them a few minutes ago

Comment: Select All + Copy to clipboard + Paste in text editor + Find. Not a great solution by any stretch, but if page context is not so important, then it just might be "good enough" to work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoyance for sure. I found a decent workaround in Chrome 92 (Aug 2021). This can probably be done in other browsers.

1. Load the stuff you need to search. This might mean scrolling a lot.
2. Right click the page, select "Inspect"
3. (this brings up the developer tools, where you can see the markup)
4. Move the developer tools into a place where you can see the dev tools and the page at the same time
5. Make sure the "Elements" window is selected so that you can see the page markup
6. Cmd-F or Ctrl-F to bring up search
7. Search for your text
8. If the text is found and it's the right text right click on that element and select "Scroll into view". Otherwise search for the next piece of text.
9. Now, the previous step might not have worked. In that case find the `<div>` element that that element is inside of and right click on it and select "Scroll into view"

This should bring the portion of the page you were trying to find into view.

This process might require a little trial and error. This is how I find a reddit comment that I've made but want to go back to. If it isn't on the first page of comments the search in page won't find it.

It's not guaranteed to work but it's better than the standard search.